# Lubuntu doesn't see Ethernet and Wireless connection on Dell 1300 Inspiron

Tags: networking, wireless, lubuntu, network-manager, ethernet

I just installed Lubuntu on Dell 1300. But I can't connect to Internet on this laptop and so I can't install all updates and drivers. I didn't find any information about my problem for Ethernet connection and I don't know how to solve this problem. Can you help me?

Output of lspci -knn | grep -EA2 'Eth|Net'

```
02:03.0 Network controller [0280]: Broadcom Corporation BCM4318 [AirForce One 54g] 802.11g Wireless LAN Controller [14e4:4318] (rev
 02)
    Subsystem: Dell Wireless 1370 WLAN Mini-PCI Card [1028:0005]
    Kernel driver in use: b43-pci-bridge
```

Comment: Please [edit] your question and add output of `lspci -knn | grep -EA2 'Eth|Net'` terminal command.

Comment: @Pilot6 done it

Comment: Which version of Lubuntu did you install? 64 or 32-bit?

Comment: @Pilot6 32-bit, because laptop has less than 1Gb of memory.

Comment: I gave a solution for both.

Comment: I will amend the solution for offline install.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

For a 64-bit system:

Download these files to your home folder:

http://mirrors.kernel.org/ubuntu/pool/main/b/b43-fwcutter/b43-fwcutter_018-2_amd64.deb
http://www.lwfinger.com/b43-firmware/broadcom-wl-5.100.138.tar.bz2

Then run in terminal:

```
sudo dpkg -i b43-fwcutter_018-2_amd64.deb
tar xfvj broadcom-wl-5.100.138.tar.bz2
sudo b43-fwcutter -w /lib/firmware broadcom-wl-5.100.138/linux/wl_apsta.o
```

For 32-bit:

http://mirrors.kernel.org/ubuntu/pool/main/b/b43-fwcutter/b43-fwcutter_018-2_i386.deb
http://www.lwfinger.com/b43-firmware/broadcom-wl-5.100.138.tar.bz2

```
sudo dpkg -i b43-fwcutter_018-2_i386.deb
tar xfvj broadcom-wl-5.100.138.tar.bz2
sudo b43-fwcutter -w /lib/firmware broadcom-wl-5.100.138/linux/wl_apsta.o
```

You can download the files using another computer.

The Ethernet should be fixed by

```
sudo apt-get purge bcmwl-kernel-source
```

Comment: Thanks a lot! I was trying to solve this problem during all day, but I didn't have good knowledge of linux :)